# How can I make a certain column's values input fields in material-table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have tried cellEditable, but I want to create an input field like this:
[image]

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Which library/framework are you using for material design? Is it [mui](https://mui.com/) or something else?

Comment: @AmitKumar it is material-table library

Comment: you can try overriding [cell](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding)

Comment: u mean as in the ui of the input field? and are u using mui components or tailwind CSS to style the input field

Comment: ur question is not clear